# JavaScript rare variable assignment

Tags: javascript

I have one question about JavaScript running on nodeJS v10.24.0.

Let's define two files, A, and B.

When I initialize a variable in file A

```
let SBOrder = Order; //predefined const variable with order structure
```

Now I have required the file B with:

```
const SBOrderConstructor = require('../../Constructor/SBOrderConstructor');
```

, this at the start of the document.

Ok, it's all defined, but now when I execute code a problem occurs, the SBOrderConstructor.create(SBOrder); is executed in a async await forEach (handmade, sequential read), this forEach have defined inside the variable let SBOrder = Order;,  with the proposal of  overriding data.

Let's continue, in the file B (SBOrderConstructor) there is defined a delete json.argument (the variable json is passed in the function), when this is executed, the second time that forEach runs throws an error TypeError SBOrder.argument.subargument is not defined, if this part of code (delete json.argument) is not runned, all works fine.

Code example:

File A:

```
const SBOrderConstructor = require('file');
const CallFunction = async(req,res,next) => {
 const Order = {argument: {subargument:true}}
 asyncForEach(array,async(element,I) => {
   let SBOrder = Order;
   SBOrderConstructor.create(SBOrder);
  }
 );
}
async function asyncForEach(array,callback) {
 for(let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
 }
}
```

File B (SBOrderConstructor):

```
static async create(json) {
 if(condition) delete json.argument; //TypeError is thrown later
 else //code works fine
 //does some stuff like saving it to the database
 return true;
}
```

Now the console throws in the second round of the asyncForEach an error:

```
TypeError json.argument.subargument is not defined.
```

The reason because I included the handmade asyncForEach is because when the forEach was in pararrel the data is being mixed. let SBOrder is mixed in the two executions.

I hope I have explained it clearly enough, Thanks in advice.

Comment: You need to include more of the code. Show us the `SBOrderConstructor.create` and the `delete.json`.

Comment: _"I hope I have explained it clearly enough"_ - seeing the relevant code along with your explanation will make it easy for others to understand your question.

Comment: It's now shown.

Comment: @MarcosNúñez, Why do you have to delete json.argument? Just remove that and your code will work fine.

Comment: If i not remove it the data of json.argument is saved in the database, and it's not valid data (i can delete it before because the constructor decides if update or create the data) (is an update query)

Comment: Also I would like to know why this occurs.

Comment: What if you try changing: `delete json.argument;` to `{json = {...json}; delete json.argument;}`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by moving the require SBOrderConstructor inside the forEach, but I would like to know how to evade this.